# Opening activity from notification issued from service not working

Tags: push-notification, android-pendingintent

I'm having a really bad time trying to open an activity from a notification my app is receiving from an application server I've set up.  I have an android service that is run when a user logs into the app server, which handles receiving notifications.  An activity called "Notifications" is supposed to be launched when the user clicks on the notification.  The relevant code on the Android service:

```
int requestID = (int) System.currentTimeMillis();

Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(this, Notifications.class));      
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
//intent.putExtra("json", message);
PendingIntent pintent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, requestID, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

Then, after setting title and text for the notification:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.plus)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(caption)
            .setContentIntent(pintent)
            .setLights(Color.BLUE, 1000, 1000)
            .setVibrate(new long[] {0, 100, 100, 100});

NotificationManager mNotifyMgr = 
        (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

mNotifyMgr.notify(100, mBuilder.build());
```

The `Notifications` Activity in its entirety:

```
package com.myapp;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class Notifications extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_notifications);
    }
}
```

I have declared my Activity in the manifest file:

```
<activity
    android:name=".Notifications"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_notifications"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:launchMode="singleTask"
    android:taskAffinity=""
    android:excludeFromRecents="true">
</activity>
```

What I am baffled about is that this specific activity will not open - I have tried setting it to open other activities and it works just fine then.  Here is my logcat from when the precise moment I click on the notification:

```
04-26 23:43:33.301: D/StatusBar(896): Clicked on content of 0|com.myapp|100|null|10107
04-26 23:43:33.312: I/ActivityManager(725): START u0 {flg=0x10008000 cmp=com.myapp/com.google.android.gms.games.Notifications (has extras)} from uid 10107 on display 0
04-26 23:43:33.315: D/audio_hw_primary(189): out_set_parameters: enter: usecase(1: low-latency-playback) kvpairs: routing=2
04-26 23:43:33.322: W/InputMethodManagerService(725): Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@6bbbbe3 attribute=null, token = android.os.BinderProxy@2c3766bc
04-26 23:43:33.326: D/audio_hw_primary(189): select_devices: out_snd_device(2: speaker) in_snd_device(0: none)
04-26 23:43:33.326: D/msm8974_platform(189): platform_send_audio_calibration: sending audio calibration for snd_device(2) acdb_id(15)
04-26 23:43:33.326: D/audio_hw_primary(189): enable_snd_device: snd_device(2: speaker)
04-26 23:43:33.330: D/audio_hw_primary(189): enable_audio_route: apply and update mixer path: low-latency-playback
04-26 23:43:33.703: D/PhoneStatusBar(896): disable: < expand icons* alerts system_info* back home recent clock search >
```

Does it have something to do with the `com.google.android.gms.games.Notifications` text seen in the logcat? I'm running Android 5.1 on a Nexus 5.

## Edit

So, I renamed the Activity to `Notification` and now all is well.  I don't have a suitable explanation as to why it fails in the first place, so I'm going to leave this question up until/if someone may adequately explain what was happening in the first place, since I'm not about to spend any more time on it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is pretty clear what happened. You have this code to set up the notification `Intent`:

```
intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(this, Notifications.class));
```

You must have imported the package `com.google.android.gms.games` so that the compiler uses `com.google.android.gms.games.Notifications` instead of your own class. When you changed the name of your class, the compiler was able to choose the correct class. Have a look at your `import` statements.